# Swift: SKSpriteNode not recognising boundaries of physicsBody

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I have this object that is a SKSpriteNode created from an image. The whole scene area itself is the boundary from where this object should not escape. Top and bottom boundaries are recognised but not the sides? Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
    import SpriteKit
    var ship = SKSpriteNode()
    class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.8)
    ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spark")
    ship.position = CGPointMake(200, 400)
    ship.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0
    ship.physicsBody.restitution = 0.95
    ship.physicsBody.friction = 0
    self.addChild(ship)
    var myVector = CGVectorMake(20, 20)
    ship.physicsBody.applyImpulse(myVector)
    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "myExhaust")
    emitter.position = CGPointMake(0.0, -ship.size.height / 2.0)
    ship.addChild(emitter)
    emitter.targetNode = self
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

    // ship.position = [touch locationInNode:self];
    ship.position = touch.locationInNode(self)
}

}
```

Comment: Have you turned on `showsPhysics` in your `SKView` to see where the `physicsBody` actually is? I suspect that your scene's `frame` doesn't have an `origin` of `(0,0)` and that's mis-aligning your `physicsBody`.

Comment: Thanks Mike S. I've turned on skView.showsPhysics = true, yes frame boundaries are misaligned (blue lines top/bottom not sides) but not sure how to define frame boundaries? skView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) or
        skView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) doesn't work.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `SKScene`'s size to create a `CGRect` and don't use `SKScene.frame` directly. `SKScene.size` determines the size of the visible portion of the `SKScene` and may be different from `SKScene.frame.size`.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    // ...
}
```

*(Side Note: with Swift you don't need to use `self` there)*

Comment: Thanks Mike S. Sorted it now. I Hadn't set a scene size in the GameView controller. Used scene.size = skView.bounds.size.